# pydantic.Field works incorrectly with custom data type

Tags: python, pydantic

I created my data type

```
from re import match
from typing import Callable

import pydantic
from pydantic.validators import str_validator

class Password(str):
    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls) -> Callable:
        yield str_validator
        yield cls.validate

    @classmethod
    def validate(cls, value: str) -> str:
        regexp = (
            r"(?=.*?[a-z])"
            r"(?=.*?[A-Z])"
            r"(?=.*?[0-9])"
        )
        if not match(regexp, value):
            raise ValueError(
                "Password must contain at least one "
                "lower/upper case letter, one digit."
            )
        return value
```

But when I'm trying to use it with pydantic.Field

```
class MyModel(pydantic.BaseModel):
    password: Password = pydantic.Field(min_length=8, max_length=128)
```

It isn't validated.

Note: I use custom data type because I want to reuse it.

Comment: At the moment Pydantic does not support simultaneous using of custom data type and field's constraints. Therefore, put all you checks inside `validate()` method.

Comment: Additionally, in your example the usage of a custom data type might not be necessary if you are just adding an additional validation that uses a regex. That could be done with the `regex` argument of `Field()` or even with a `@validator("password")`.